# Datatables-editor : How to include plugins

Tags: datatables, datetimepicker, jquery-datatables-editor

The datatable editor (after the completed purchase of a developer license) avails  a slew of additional plug-ins.  One such example is "Bootstrap DateTimePicker".  However, after following the guide on the page, I could not get the plugin to work.

I've included the external libraries of css and .js files.  I've also added the necessary codes to declare the field type as "datetime".

```
"label": "Updated date:",
"name": "updated_date",
"type": "datetime",
```

Lastly, I included the additional Plug-in codes (.js) at the header with the rest of the .js script.

On testdrive, the form showed both date and time in text.  However, the anticipated "pretty" bootstrap datetimepicker UI does not show.

Can anyone offer any pointers?

Comment: Please show what JS files do you include. Also please show your DataTables full initialization code.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have included all the correct .js and .css libraries as stated.

You probably just haven't initiated datepicker.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  ... your datatables and editor configuration ...

 $('.input-datepicker').datepicker();//<-- Initiates datepicker

//replace '.input-datepicker' with the class of your input element

});
```